# Is there a way to disable "low disk space" alert in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, alert

For quite some time my hard disk is almost used up and the low disk space alert keeps on popping up which is really annoying. Is there a way to disable this alert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://brainwreckedtech.wordpress.com/2009/01/26/turning-off-low-disk-space-warnings-in-windows-vista-7/) suggests the following registry change:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Create a new key, "NoLowDiskSpaceChecks" as a DWORD, and set it to 1.

Comment: Actually, you want to add a new DWORD value, not a new key.